# Getting control that fired postback in page_init

Tags: asp.net, postback

I have a gridview that includes dynamically created dropdownlist. When changing the dropdown values and doing a mass update on the grid (btnUpdate.click), I have to create the controls in the page init so they will be available to the viewstate. However, I have several other buttons that also cause a postback and I don't want to create the controls in the page init, but rather later in the button click events.

How can I tell which control fired the postback while in page_init? __EVENTTARGET = "" and request.params("btnUpdate") is nothing

Answer (score 7):

It is possible to determine which control caused a PostBack by looking at `Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"]`.  The problem with this is that button ids will not show unless you set their [UseSubmitBehavior](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.usesubmitbehavior%28VS.80%29.aspx) to **false**.  Here's an example:

**.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        switch (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"].ToString())
        {
            case "ddlOne":
                break;
            case "btnOne":
                break;
            case "btnTwo":
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

**.aspx**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
  <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlOne" AutoPostBack="true" runat="server">
      <asp:ListItem Text="One" Value="One" />
      <asp:ListItem Text="Two" Value="Two" />
  </asp:DropDownList>  
  <asp:Button ID="btnOne" Text="One" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" />
  <asp:Button ID="btnTwo" Text="Two" UseSubmitBehavior="false" runat="server" />
</form>
```

Comment: you should use UniqueID to match with the value of Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"].ToString() the ID of the control alone is not enough