# Button click doesn't call function even when button attribute OnClick is set to that function

Tags: asp.net

I have an aspx page with two buttons, one of the buttons has an OnClick attribute to a function that should be run when clicked.  When the other button is clicked there is an if statement checking if the page is a postback, if it is then I run some statements that need to be run when that button is clicked.  That postback button works fine.  However, the other button, when it's clicked the function it's supposed to call never executes, and the statements inside if (Page.IsPostBack) get executed instead.  What can I do to fix this?  Is there a way to make the button that calls a function not do a Post back?

Comment: Can you post the code. Both in the aspx page and the code behind.

Comment: Are you wanting asynchronous postbacks? (AJAX)

Comment: I don't want a postback at all to be performed from a button click, I just want the function specified in the OnClick attribute of the button to get executed.

Comment: A button will always cause a postback, unless you use AJAX (eg UpdatePanel, jquery.ajax(), etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*[snip - not part of the question]*

**EDIT:** Here's an example of calling a button's `OnClick` function in an asych way using an `UpdatePanel`:

**.aspx**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
    <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upTest" runat="server">
        <ContentTemplate>
            <asp:Button ID="btnTest" Text="Test" OnClick="Delete_Click"  runat="server" />
        </ContentTemplate>
    </asp:UpdatePanel>
</form>
```

**.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Delete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Whatever you want to do.
}
```

**EDIT 2**: Here's an answer I gave recently that [figures out what control has caused a postback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2479175/getting-control-that-fired-postback-in-page-init/2479544#2479544).

Comment: The OnClick attribute is set to "Delete_Click" and I have a method protected void Delete_Click() in the aspx.cs file

Comment: The `OnClick` is a server-side function that's expected to be called as part of a postback.  If you don't want a full postback then you should look at an `UpdatePanel` for an asynch call.

Comment: I figured out my problem sort of.  The Page_Load function gets called before my Delete_Click funtion.  And in the Page_Load funciton, I have to have if (Page.IsPostback) { //do stuff then redirect page} so that is why Delete_Click doesn't get called.  Can I use the object sender to determine which button caused the Post back?

Comment: I set the delete button's UseSubmitBehavior to false.  Then inside if (Page.IsPostback) i have if (Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"].ToString() == "DeleteButton") { //do delete button stuff} else {//do other button stuff} and when I click on DeleteButton it still does the other button's stuff

Comment: Note that The delete buttons id is equal to DeleteButton

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "does the other button's stuff".  Are you saying your if statement is evaluating to false?  Are you watching what the value of Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"] is during the postback?

Comment: Yes, I now looked at Request.Form["__EVENTTARGET"], it was close to DeleteButton, but had some other text in it, I changed my if statement to check for it and it works. Thank you so much for staying with me the whole time

Comment: You're very welcome.  It's possible for the id to come back mangled if the control is within an INamingContainer.